# Match last occurence in a string

Tags: regex

I am looking for an regex to match the substring from the last occurence of `c` (before the word `blah`) up to the word `blah`:

input:

```
acacacacadddddblahacacac
```

output should be `cadddddblah`.

Is that possible at all?

UPDATE

How would it look like if I search for another word instead of for the letter `c`?

input:

```
acblhacacacadddddblahacacac
```

I am searching for `blh` to `blah`. Result should be `blhacacacadddddblah`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`searching for blh to blah`  This is one way. Not very clean though.
Just gets inner blh .. blah

```
blh(?:(?!blh|blah).)*blah
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this :

```
c[^c]*?blah
```

Comment: You don't need the `?` modifier.

Comment: @Barmar: The goal of the lazy quantifier is to stop at the first "blah" if there is more than one "blah".

Answer (score 2):

Just match a sequence that doesn't include `c` between `c` and `blah`.

```
c[^c]*blah
```

Comment: Matches all blah's up to the _last_ `blah` if it can. The OP didn't mention sub blah's though.

Comment: @user1414745 Looks like sin's answer solves the updated question, but I'm not very expert at negative lookaheads. Try it and see.

Answer (score 1):

This regex should do the trick

```
c[^c]*blah
```

http://rubular.com/r/dotNrEH8gW

Comment: Where is `blah` in your regex?

Comment: @Barmar sorry, i thought it was until end of string at first